# How to delete a cells from from one column in a DataFrame with a condition on python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-cleaning

I am interested in finding out, in the example dataframe that I have created below column 1 which is var1, I want to remove a cell where the string inside has the letter `Z`. But I do not want to remove the entire entire row. How can I go about to do this, I thought I might need to use `.str.replace()` but I do know where to start. (A disclaimer this is tutorial question)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"var1": ["AZZBBAA", "CCDDDED", "DZZZZFD", "CDEEEEFG"],
                  "var2": [1,2,4,5]})
```

Which gives me:

```
    var1      var2
0   AZZBBAA     1
1   CCDDDED     2
2   DZZZZFD     4
3   CDEEEEFG    5
```

My desired output is below:

```
    var1      var2
0               1
1   CCDDDED     2
2               4
3   CDEEEEFG    5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Series.str.replace()` is also feasible in your case:

```
df['var1'] = df['var1'].str.replace('.*Z.*', "")
```

this will clear the value of `var1` column if it contains `Z` char

---

```
       var1  var2
0               1
1   CCDDDED     2
2               4
3  CDEEEEFG     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['var1'].str.contains('Z'), 'var1'] = '' # or float('nan')
```

Or [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['var1'] = df['var1'].mask(df['var1'].str.contains('Z'))
```

Output:

```
       var1  var2
0               1
1   CCDDDED     2
2               4
3  CDEEEEFG     5
```